# Execute SQL CTE using SQLAlchemy and Python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have the following code in the main program:

```
cleanDuplicatesAttendeesSQL = attendees.clean_duplicates()
sqlUtilities.databaseWorkerExecute(cleanDuplicatesAttendeesSQL)
```

`attendees.clean_duplicates()` sets the variable `cleanDuplicatesAttendeesSQL`:

```
def clean_duplicates():
    return """
        WITH cte AS(
            SELECT [Sessions]
                ,[Confirmation #]
                ,[First Name]
                ,[Last Name]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY
                        [Sessions]
                        ,[Confirmation #]
                        ,[First Name]
                        ,[Last Name]
                    ORDER BY
                        [Sessions]
                        ,[Confirmation #]
                        ,[First Name]
                        ,[Last Name]
                    ) row_num
            FROM attendees
        )
        DELETE FROM cte
        WHERE row_num > 1"""
```

I then pass `cleanDuplicatesAttendeesSQL` to the following function to execute against the database:

```
def databaseWorkerExecute (sql):
    engine = sqlalchemy_connect()
    try:

        engine.execute(sql)
        print("Execution successful.")
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error = str(e.__dict__['orig'])
        print (error)
        sys.exit("Execution was not sucessful. Exiting the program...")
```

This function does not error, I get an "Execution successful" every time. However, when I look at the table in the database I still see duplicates. I successfully use this same `databaseWorkerExecute` function to do other things like updates, inserts, and deletes. How can I get the CTE to also work?

Screenshot of SQL output:
[image: Screenshot of SQL output]

Comment: Are you sure, therefore, that your `PARTITION BY` clause is correct? We don't have access to your data, so we don't know if the above is actually working as you expect.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, the `PARTITION BY` clause seems to be working. I just added a screenshot of the SQL output.

Comment: are you missing a `commit` in case you run inside the transaction?

Comment: Have you watched the query play out via Extended Events or SQL Profiler? SQLAlchemy uses regex-based query parsers on statements to figure out if it should autocommit [based on the presence of DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#library-level-e-g-emulated-autocommit). It's possible that such behaviour is bugged (lacks `re.MULTILINE`) and you might need to set [transaction isolation levels](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-including-dbapi-autocommit) to get the desired outcome.

Comment: @van @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the resources. I changed the `try` of `databaseWorkerExecute` to `try: with engine.begin() as trans: trans.execute(sql) print("Execution successful.")` based off the information I found on this [GitHub post](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5492). This has resolved my issue.

Comment: using engine.begin() solves it for me too.